# Why oldCartRemovalJob is placed in the <custom-name>commercewebservices?

Tags: java, spring, cart, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to remove old carts. Hybris has a job called oldCartRemovalJob but it is within the **custom-name_commercewebservices** but I do not use the  "custom-name_commercewebservices" in any custom extension since commercewebservices extension is based on RESTful web services to be able to connect with Hybris platform anywhere.

What is best practice to use oldCartRemovalJob? writing it from scratch (copy-paste everything about existing job) in a platform custom extension?  Or using requires-extension **custom-name_commercewebservices**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any custom requirement, you can use `CartRemovalJob` present in **acceleratorservices**. Simply run below Impex to configure your cleanup job. Replace myStore & mySite with your values.

```
$storeUid=myStore
$siteUid=mySite


# Cart Cleanup CronJobs (instance of CartRemovalCronJob)  
INSERT_UPDATE CartRemovalCronJob ; code[unique=true]      ; job(code)[default=cartRemovalJob] ; sites(uid)[default=$siteUid] ; sessionLanguage(isoCode)[default=en]
                                 ; $siteUid-CartRemovalJob

# Trigger for your job
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger ; cronJob(code)[unique=true]    ; second ; minute ; hour ; day ; month ; year ; relative ; active ; maxAcceptableDelay
                      ; $siteUid-CartRemovalJob       ; 0      ; 0      ; 5    ; -1  ; -1    ; -1   ; false    ; true   ; -1
```

**Configure Cart removal age -** You can configure cartRemoval age for logged-in customers. The default value is 28 days (2419200 seconds).

```
INSERT_UPDATE BaseSite ; uid[unique=true] ; cartRemovalAge  
                       ; mySite           ; 2419200
```

**Configure Anonymous cart removal age -** As same as above, you can also configure cartRemovalAge for anonymous users. The default value is 14 days (1209600 seconds).

```
INSERT_UPDATE BaseSite ; uid[unique=true] ; anonymousCartRemovalAge
                       ; mySite           ; 1209600
```

Answer (score 0):

In hybris you have two jobs that are quite similar :

- OldCartRemovalJob in `ycommercewebservices`.
- CartRemovalJob in `acceleratorservices`.

`ycommercewebservices` is part of the `commercewebservices` module. If you don't plan to use this module then use the one from `acceleratorservices`.

However including `acceleratorservices` might be a bad idea because the project has other dependencies., if you don't want a dependency on the cms for exemple then you should just copy/paste the code from one job in your project.

Now how to choose between the two jobs? (yes they are actually different)

- if you want the "max ages" to be set on the site then use `CartRemovalJob`
- if you want the "max ages" to be set on the job then use `OldCartRemovalJob`

---

Summary :

- use the jobs from existing extensions if you already use these extensions
- if you're not using any of them copy/paste the job to avoid the creation of useless dependencies
- work on the job that fit the most your needs